# What can we do to encourage advertising of this site?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

One thing that we seem to need, looking at our [stats so far](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4470/martial-arts), are simply more avid users.

So the question is: How can we direct more traffic here? Not just at the level of keyword advertising, SEO, or anything else that broad, but what specific venues, online or off, might be a good fit for trying to see if we can recruit more people here?  Is anyone here a member of a social venue where they already are actively recruiting, and if you have tried but without much luck what do you think we could do which would encourage those people to join the site?

Comment: Who exactly do you want to bring to the site? It should be obvious given that this is martial arts, but I think identifying and being specific about that is more important than the how.

Answer (score 1):

Last week I answered a martial arts question on a forum and left a link to a relevant question on this site. I'm hoping that people will follow the link, find this site interesting and decide to join. I'm not sure how effective it is, but it's the best way I can think of to promote this site.

Also, I think we have to keep the stats in mind, but at the same time not worry too much about them. To quote from [this blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/does-this-site-have-a-chance-of-succeeding/)
"*The Area 51 summary does not represent some sort of “report card” filled with pass/fail grades*". Many beta websites fail to reach good questions/day, and visits/day levels, but as long as the traffic doesn't decline and questions still get answered we'll be okay.

Comment: The other thing is what Area51 is showing is apparently an average generated over the life of the site. I suspect we're doing considerably better than we see, at least in terms of traffic...

Comment: @stslavik I just found out that when you hover over the first statistic in Area51 it says "1.4 questions a day on average over the last 2 weeks". But there is no interval mentioned when hovering over the other stats.

Comment: That figure I agree with... The visits per day I question a bit...

Answer (score 1):

We need more good questions, even if we know the answers.  And we need those questions open longer.

What also helps is adding links to questions in other forums, facebook, etc.  Those external links help increase the page ranking in several search engines, which in turn attract more traffic.